# What's the best way to use Task.WhenAll for List<foo> array and inside it get foo values to run scripts?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Is there a way to convert this to `Task.WhenAll()` and have smaller part of scripts run it's own process independently?  I'm new to parallelism and trying to figure out of what's the best way to do this.

```
var emailManager = new EmailManager();
var repository = new Repository();

foreach(var v in ProfileLookup())
{
   await emailManager.ExportCsvAsync(
       repository.GetRecords(v.AccountId),
       v.EmailAddress,
       "Purchases.csv"
   );
}
```

What I see is `ProfileLookup()` return a List<> array of objects (like `v.EmailAddress`, `v.AccountId`, etc.) which can be use in `Task.WhenAll()`.  So, how would I enclosed `repository.GetRecords()` and `emailManager.ExportCsvAsync()` in a seperate call that get the `v.AccountId` and `v.EmailAddress` from within `Task.WhenAll()` this way.

That is one way I see is to do this.  If you have better suggestion then I'm all ear.  I'm new to parallelism and still trying to get the hang of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can project each value from `ProfileLookup()`  using `Enumerable.Select`. This won't make anything run in it's own process, it will make the call to `ExportCsvAsync` concurrently:

```
var tasks = ProfileLookup().Select(v => emailManager.ExportCsvAsync(
   repository.GetRecords(v.AccountId),
   v.EmailAddress,
   "Purchases.csv"));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```